# Apache Storm Topology using Flux YAML file

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-flux

I am designing an Apache Storm topology using a Flux YAML topology definition file.  The trouble is I don't see how to :-

1. Create a stream that sends to multiple bolts (the syntax seems to only include one 'to:'  line).
2. Emit multiple named streams from a single bolt.  This is perfectly legal in Apache Storm.  I am concerned that the Stream 'name:' line is declared as 'optional - not used' and hence Flux does not seem to support this feature of Storm ?

Comment: Ah, I see the answer to question 1.  Each destination needs to be listed as a separate stream as they have individual grouping definitions.

However, question 2 is still a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Each destination needs to be listed as a separate stream as they have individual grouping definitions.
2. I don't think that's possible with Flux (0.10.0) yet.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess I'll have to amend the Flux parser for my own requirements.